# How to count up (and display the numbers as they are counted) to infinity at a certain rate per second?

Tags: javascript, html, counter

Let's say I'm making a farming game and I want a span to read "0 tomato plants" and count up at 4 tomato plants per second. I haven't the slightest idea of how to form this (I'm really new to javascript) and I can't find anything online. Essentially I'm trying to make something similar to [Candy Box](http://candies.aniwey.net).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, this is not the forum to learn very basic technology. The `date` object might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function(){function_to_plant_4_tomatos()},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the setTimeout() function.

Comment: Only if OP does not care about accuracy.